# Формат времени в MySql

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно получить формат времени так:

```
18 авг.
```

Делаю так:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d')  as day, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M')  as month
```

Получаю:

```
18 August
```

Как получить сокращенное и на русском языке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте  lc_time_names и соответствующую локализацию.
То есть, перед выполнение запроса для получения русских названий выполните

```
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU'
```

Более подробно можно почитать тут https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html, там же можно найти перечень всех доступных локализаций.